# How do I tell exactly what time an answer was posted?

Tags: discussion, timestamps

When answers to a question are posted it is indicated (above the poster's ID) in-terms of the time difference between now and the time of the post.  In the early minutes after an answer, that time is rounded to the minute.

Just curious, but does it round up or down?  Or does it go to the closest minute?

The reason I ask, is because on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928231/order-by-different-the-others-table-id-in-my-sql/8928293#8928293) today Joe and I posted within a short time of each other.  His did not appear until after I posted mine.  Yet, in the comments someone comes-out and accuses me of poaching Joe's answer saying "there's 2 minutes between the answers."  I wanted to reply with something to the effect of it being a potential difference of 61 seconds or so, but I didn't want to assume that it rounds-up.

Comment: You can hover over the description of the time to get the exact time of the post, in UTC.

Comment: Deleted those comments, as they are completely not constructive.  I'd not worry about it.

Comment: Everybody who thinks the internet to be perfectly synchronous and you to be able to read and write an answer in 10 seconds begs for getting his comments flagged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just hover over most dates to see the UTC (Z or Zulu) time.

[image: hover mouse over time to see actual UTC time]